# rational squares in arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

In Washington's book on elliptic curves, there is an exercise:

Let $n$ be an integer. Show that if $x_0, y_0$ are rational numbers satisfying $y_0^2 = x_0^3 − n^2x_0$, and $x_0 \neq 0, ±n$, then the tangent line to this curve at $(x_0, y_0)$ intersects the curve in a point $(x_1, y_1)$ such that $x_1, x_1 − n, x_1 + n$ are squares of rational numbers.

Well, implicit differentiation tells us that at $(x_0,y_0)$, the slope of the tangent line is $$y' = \frac{3x_0^2-n^2}{2y_0}.$$ So, the equation defining the line tangent to the curve at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $$y = y'x + (y_0- y'x_0).$$

If we let $u := y_0- y'x_0$ then we have $(y'x+u)^2=x^3-n^3x$ for points $(x,y)$ common to the tangent line and the curve. This leads to $0 = x^3 - (y')^2x^2-(n^2+2y'u)x-u^2$. Since $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point where the line is tangent, $x_0$ is a double root of this cubic and since the third point of intersection is $(x_1,y_1)$, we have that $u^2 = x_1x_0^2$ since the product of roots is the constant term. Since $x_0 \neq 0$ and both $u$ and $x_0$ are rational, it follows that $x_1$ is the square of a rational number.

Now, I am stuck on showing that $x_1 + n$ and $x_1 - n$ are squares of rational numbers. I've looked at the coefficient of $x^2$ in the cubic mentioned above but didn't get anywhere with that and I have tried substituting $x_1 = \frac{u^2}{x_0^2}$ into various places but couldn't find anything from this as well. Perhaps I am missing something obvious but any assistance in completing this exercise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read Wikipedia [Congruent number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number#Relation_to_elliptic_curves) with relation to elliptic curdves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P = (x_0,y_0)$ be point on an elliptic curve $E$ given by  $y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c.$
Let $(x_1,y_1)$ be intersection point with tangent line.
$x_1$ is given as follows.

$$x_1 = \frac{x_0^4-2bx_0^2-8cx_0-4ac+b^2}{4y_0^2}$$

Substitute $a=0,c=0,b=-n^2$, then we get
$x_1 = \frac{(x_0^2+n^2)^2}{4y_0^2}$

Hence $x_1 - n = \frac{(-n^2-2x_0n+x_0^2)^2}{4y_0^2}, x_1 + n = \frac{(-n^2+2x_0n+x_0^2)^2}{4y_0^2}.$